# Hardware button back code not responding correctly

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

```
<Page actionBarHidden="true" @loaded="pageLoaded" @unloaded="pageUnloaded">
        <DockLayout>
            <DockLayout v-show="search">
               ...
            </DockLayout>
            <DockLayout class="routeDetails" v-show="!search">
               ...
            </DockLayout>
         </DockLayout>
</Page>

           pageLoaded: function () {
                // We only want to register the event in Android
                if (application.android) {
                    console.log("halllo");
                    application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, this.backEvent);
                }
            },
            pageUnloaded: function () {
                // We only want to un-register the event on Android
                if (application.android) {
                    console.log("done");
                    application.android.off(application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, this.backEvent);
                }
            },
            backEvent: function (args) {
                console.log("hey I pressed");
                if (this.search) {
                    args.cancel = true;
                    this.search = false;
                } else {
                    args.cancel = false;
                }
            }
```

`search` is standard `false`.

### Problem

Is when I'm on the `show` view where `search = true`. I want to press the Android hardware button back. It should be hidden and show the other one where `search = false`. But it only does that after I press the Android hardware button 2 times in a row.

But when I'm on the view where `search = false`, it logs the `console.log` after the first time I press the Android hardware button.

The code I found on [this blog post](http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=261). 
referenced in this [Github issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3259)

### Update

[Nativescript-Vue Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=UtTLMk&v=2)

So what you need to do is click on one of the buttons on the screen. 
Then use the hardware button to go back. In this example, it will do it directly. But when you try to that a second time you will need to press the hardware button 2 times before it works. In my case, I always need to press 2 times before it works.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the context, try

```
application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, this.backEvent, this);
```

Passing `this` as third parameter makes sure `this` within `backEvent` method points to Vue component.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't make any difference. The logs only disappear after I press the hardware button 2 times.

Comment: Can you share the Playground Sample where the issue is reproduced.

Comment: I will do it soon!

Comment: sorry for the late response. I got you a playground example. It's not completely the same. See explenation

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple active listeners on the activityBackPressedEvent?

You should use only the event name to remove the listener if alway there is only one active or you want to remove all of them.

```
application.android.off(application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent);
```

Comment: Sorry didn't work. I only have the event listeners that I show in the problem. Otherwise none.

Comment: I checked your shared code and it's working as expected. The only time when you need to press back twice is when you have the focus on the search input and the keyboard it's open. This is normal behaviour. Right?